# Generating "friend circles" from a dict of connections [python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of Facebook friends that looks like this:

```
connections = {
0: set([3, 4]), 
1: set([5]), 
2: set([]),
3: set([0, 4, 6]), 
4: set([0, 3]), 
5: set([1]), 
6: set([3])}
```

where this dict matches a person (i.e. 3) to his friends (0, 4, 6). Now, I want to create a set of "friend circles" such that EVERY PERSON in the friend circle is friends with EVERY OTHER PERSON in the friend circle. It should look like this:
`{{0, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {0, 4}, {0, 3}, {1, 5}, ...}`
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please visit the help center to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you post your complete expected output?

Comment: I guess you're looking for a way to have a one-to-many relationship between the connections?

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

connections = {
    0: set([3, 4]),
    1: set([5]),
    2: set([]),
    3: set([0, 4, 6]),
    4: set([0, 3]),
    5: set([1]),
    6: set([3])
}

# Generate initial friend circles a generator that yields (0, 3, 4), (1, 5), (2,) etc.
# Please keep in mind that this gets exhausted after one run,
#   if you want to reuse friend_circles later just use a list ([] instead of ())
friend_circles = (tuple(set([k]+list(v))) for (k, v) in connections.iteritems())

# Slightly modified version of python powerset recipe
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
# min_size is to specify the minimum number of people required to form a circle (2 friends in your example).
# The function further filters the resulting powerset by checking that all the members of the circle are friends with each other.
def get_valid_circles(iterable, min_size):
    s = list(iterable)
    return [
        combo for combo in chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in xrange(min_size, len(s)+1))
        if all(p2 in connections.get(p1, set()) for (p1, p2) in filter(lambda c: c[0] != c[1], product(combo, combo)))
    ]

# After retrieving all the valid circles you will end up with dupes as well as some empty sets of circles, so
# Filter the chain of circles and cast it into a set.
circles = set(
    filter(None, chain(*(get_valid_circles(friend_circle, 2) for friend_circle in friend_circles)))
)
print "Final filtered circles"
print circles

# If you want the unfiltered results you can just use this:
#   if you come up with an empty result here, see my note above on friend_circles generator
# print "Final unfiltered circles"
# print [get_valid_circles(friend_circle, 2) for friend_circle in friend_circles]
```

This prints

```
Final filtered circles
set([(0, 3, 4), (1, 5), (3, 6), (0, 4), (0, 3), (3, 4)])
```

Comment: Wait - (0, 3, 6) should not be a friend circle, because 0 is not friends with 6.

Comment: @NeilChowdhuryo_O check my final edit, sorry it took a while.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to expand all the friend sets, so for person `0`, his friends sets become

```
{0,3}, {0,4}, {0,3,4}
```

Person `1` becomes:

```
{1,5}
```

Person `3` becomes:

```
{3,0}, {3,4}, {3,6}, {3,0,4}, {3,0.6}, {3,4,6}, {3,0,4,6}
```

Once you've expanded all of them, then loop through each person again and check each of the friends in the expanded friend sets to see if they also contain that same expanded friend set.  If each friend in the friend set contains that friend set, then it's a *friend circle*.  Store those friend circles.  If you want, you can remove *sub-circles* by checking if any circles are subsets of others.  For instance `{0,3}` is a subset of `{0,3,4}`, so it can be removed.